# nable to load one or more of the requested types.\r\nCould not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.6.1.0

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly, assemblies, sqlclient

I have an application written on the top of ASP.NET Core 3.1.

When I use reflection to get the types in my project, I get the following exception

```
Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.6.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I am not sure what package depends on `System.Data.SqlClient` but my app does not depend on `System.Data.SqlClient` package.

I tried to install the `System.Data.SqlClient` into my project the following command, but I am still getting the same error.

```
Install-Package System.Data.SqlClient -Version 4.6.1
```

Here is my code

```
// Loading the dlls.
var loadedAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList();

var referencedPaths = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "*.dll");
var loadables = referencedPaths.Where(r => !loadedAssemblies.Select(a => a.Location).Contains(r, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList();

foreach(var loadable in loadables)
{
    try
    {
        loadedAssemblies.Add(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(path)));
    }
    catch { }
}


Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
List<Type> types = new List<Type>();

foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
{
    try
    {
        types.AddRange(assembly.GetTypes());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // I get the exception here 
        // Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
        // Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.6.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
    }
}
```

How can I determine what is causing this issue? How can I solve it?

Comment: What is the connection string?  Usually this type error is due to the application attaching to the mdf file instead of connecting the the SQL Server.  The attach in the connection string is not needed if the database is already attached to a server.  When the mdf file is on a remote machine the client does not have access to the mdf file.  Also the SQL Server owns the mdf file and doesn't allow users to open the mdf file what attached to a server.

Comment: The connection string is stored in appsettings.json file and it is pointing to an instance of a SQL Server. there is local mdf file in my project

Comment: You do not need the localdb if there is also an instance of the SQL Server.  Remove the Attachdb which contains the localdb.

Comment: @jdweng I don't have a local database. The connection is ponting to a server not a localhost

Comment: I know.  Do you have an Attach File with LocaDb or a path to the mdf?  The attached is not needed which is probably causing the error.  If not then you are trying to connect to a database on server that doesn't exist or your credentials are wrong.

Comment: There is no file attached. This has nothing to do with the connection to the database. If I ignore the error and app runs but not all the types get loaded because of this error.

Comment: Exception says "The system cannot find the file specified".  Do you have more than one database on the server?  Each database on the server is a separate mdf file.  The code also looks like it imports data into the database.  So may be the import files have wrong credentials or are in a folder that is not accessible to the user that is logged in.  I usually debug issues like this by using SQL Server Management Studio and try query from SSMS.  The error messages are better in SSMS than c#.  Is the error message from the ldf log file?

Comment: I think it is saying that it can't file the .dll file not the mdf

Comment: The base directory is where the c# executable is located.  You may want to open the csproj with note pad to see what is in the build instructions.